# Ext.grid.ColumnModel minimum width and auto resize column

Tags: extjs3, gridpanel

How to set minimum width in `Ext.grid.ColumnModel`? Also, is there any property for auto resize column for length of content?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `minColumnWidth` for all columns in grid (this is grid config option).

You can use `autoExpandColumn` to set one column which will adjust it's size. For that column you can also set `autoExpandMin` and `autoExpandMax` to constrain it's max/min width.